# Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional with $\dim V \geq 2$. Prove that there exist $S,T \in L(V,V)$ such that $ST\neq TS$

Tags: linear-algebra

Does this have anything to do with basis? If this is talking about the identity map, I don't understand why $TS$ and $ST$ would be different. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a specific example which holds for $V$ a vector space over *any* field $\Bbb F$.  Suppose first that $\dim V = 2$; then picking any basis $\{v_1, v_2\}$ for $V$, we define in that basis the operators $N_1, N_2 \in L(V, V)$ as folllows:

$N_1(v_1) = 0, \; N_1(v_2) = v_1;  \tag{1}$

$N_2(v_1) = v_2, \; N _2(v_2) = 0. \tag{2}$

Then for any vector $w = av_1 + bv_2$ we have

$N_2N_1(w) = aN_2N_1(v_1) + bN_2N_1(v_2) = bv_2, \tag{3}$

but

$N_1N_2(w) = aN_1N_2(v_1) + bN_1N_2(v_2) = av_1; \tag{4}$

We see from (3) and (4) and the linear independence of $v_1, v_2$ that

$N_1N_2(w) \ne N_2N_1(w) \tag{5}$

unless $a = b = 0$, that is, unless $w = 0$.  Thus

$N_1N_2 \ne N_2N_1 \tag{6}$

as operators in $L(V, V)$.  In the event that $\dim V = n > 2$, we may build upon the construction of $N_1, N_2$ as follows:  choosing a basis $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ for $V$, we now define $N_1$, $N_2$ on $v_1$, $v_2$ as above, and set

$N_1(v_i) = N_2(v_i) = 0 \tag{7}$

for $3 \le i \le n$.  Then for any $w = \sum a_i v_i \in V$ we have as above

$N_1N_2(w) \ne N_2N_1(w) \tag{8}$

provided at least one of $a_1, a_2 \ne 0$.   Thus

$N_1N_2 \ne N_2N_1. \tag{9}$

We have thus shown that for any finite dimensional vector space $V$ over any field $\Bbb F$, $\dim V > 1$ implies the esistence of a noncommuting pair of operators $S, T \in L(V, V)$:  $TS \ne ST$.  ***QED***

***Note:***  I think it is worth pointing out that both $N_1N_2$ and $N_2N_1$ are *idempotent* operators; that is, $(N_1N_2)^2 = N_1N_2$ etc.  This may easily be seen by evaluating $(N_1N_2)^2$ on $w = \sum a_i v_i$.  In fact we have that $N_1N_2(v_1) = v_1$, and likewise $N_2N_1(v_2) = v_2$ with $N_1N_2(v_i) = N_2N_1(v_i) = 0$ for $i >2$; $N_2N_1$ and $N_1N_2$ are thus projections onto the subspaces $\langle v_1 \rangle$ and $\langle v_2 \rangle$, respectively.  Furthermore we see that $N_1$, $N_2$ are themselves *nilpotent* operators, i.e. $N_i^2 = 0$, $i = 1, 2$.  This in turn implies that the projectors $N_1N_2$ and $N_2N_1$ are *orthogonal*  in the sense that $(N_1N_2)(N_2N_1) = N_1N_2^2N_1 = N_1(0)N_1 = 0$ etc.  We also see that when $\dim V = 2$, $N_1N_2 + N_2N_1 = I_V$, the identity map on $V$.  All these properties have appropriate generalizations to the case $\dim V > 2$; I leave them for my readership to discover and prove; the task is not difficult.  And though these assertions take us somewhat beyond the scope of the original question, they come for free with the answer!  ***End of Note.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 3):

By selecting a basis, it is enough to consider the case where $\dim V = 2$.  In other words, we are looking for two $2\times 2$ matrices that do not commute.

Comment: Then would it be sufficient to say that since dimV=2, there are two vectors that are linearly independent that do not commute? I know they aren't scalar multiples of one another but I don't know how to show that two vectors are not commutable. Thanks!

Comment: @aralc It doesn't mean anything to say that two vectors do not commute, since there is no multiplication defined on vectors.  You are looking for two linear transformations $V\to V$, which you can think of (after a choice of basis) as $2\times 2$ matrices.  You are looking for matrices $S$ and $T$ such that $ST\neq TS$.